# Should I use a reverse proxy (eg NGINX) inside my Kuberenetes cluster?

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, kubernetes

I have setup a Kubernetes cluster (on GKE). Running multiple services but mainly serving a webapp through a stock Ingress controller.

Are there any benefits to running a reverse proxy behind the Ingress? The TLS is terminated at this point, so it's not for that. Maybe for some server hardening?

Comment: None. It's kind of the point of Ingresses on Cloud providers like GKE. You don't need to do the hard part of having VIPs and LBs setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only advantage of chaining GKE ingress and Nginx is ability to use more advanced configuration provided by Nginx.

Currently there are benefits of running your own reverse proxy skipping ingress. Or to use [custom ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx) instead of GKE one. The main benefits of doing this is:

- Cost saving, each GKE ingress resource costs money.
- Advanced routing/config offered by Nginx or other proxy.
- Bypasses the current GKE Ingress beta limitations.